# Where did my command (Heroku) go?

Tags: macos, bash, ruby, rvm

I expect to be schooled on this but have exhausted my Google searches and scant knowledge of how OS X finds a command.

I've been using heroku for years and for some reason today I get the result:

```
 /usr/local/bin/heroku: /usr/local/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

The first line of /usr/local/bin/heroku yields:

```
 #!/usr/local/heroku/ruby/bin/ruby
```

and I have no ruby directory at that location, but comparing it to a previous working backup I've never had it there. Instead I use RVM that points to my current ruby.

which ruby

```
 /Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby
```

So the next thing to try is which heroku

```
 /usr/local/bin//heroku
```

This throws me. Where is that extra path separator coming from? So here is the result of my echo $PATH

```
 /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin:/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/bin:/Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin:/Users/sam/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/share/python:/usr/local/bin/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin
```

ruby -v

```
 ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-darwin12.5.0]
```

Changing out the first line of /usr/local/bin/ruby to the location of ruby rvm uses above errors out on the ruby commands in this file which is odd because I don't have trouble with ruby in any other capacity.

This is probably due to some goof I've done as this is a recent phenomenon. I have restarted recently (to try out the Yosemite partition) and that's the only thing I can thing of that changed in the environment. What other bit of info would help solve this issue?, thanx, sam

Comment: The extra `/` is coming because your PATH includes `/usr/local/bin/` before listing `/usr/local/bin` (twice). Might want to look at the files that set your path (like `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`) and clean out the redundancies.

Comment: Yes, it was something added in PATH that I didn't see before. If you can turn your comment into an answer I'll happy accept it, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra `/` is coming because your PATH includes `/usr/local/bin/` before listing `/usr/local/bin` (twice). Might want to look at the files that set your path (like `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`) and clean out the redundancies.